# Python TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Anybody knows how to solve this problem? I'm studying collective intelligence now, and I compared with another example when I made this code. But It's getting error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in
 <module>
    clust=clusters.hcluster(data)   File "D:\Kuliah\smt1\Phyton Class\contoh coding\coding-collective
intelligence\myself_Maulida\bab3-documentClustering\clusters.py", line
78, in hcluster
    for i in range(len(clust[0].vec))] TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Here is my code, anybody can help? Thank you.

```
def hcluster(rows,distance=pearson):
    distances={}
    currentclustid=-1

    #clusters are initially just the rows
    clust=[bicluster(rows[i],id=i) for i in range(len(rows))]

    while len(clust)>1:
        lowestpair=(0.1)
        closest=distance(clust[0].vec,clust[1].vec)

        #loop through every pair looking for the smallest distance 
        for i in range(len(clust)):
            for j in range(i+1,len(clust)):
            #distance is the cache of distance calculations
                if(clust[i].id,clust[j].id) not in distances:
                    distances[(clust[i].id,clust[j].id)]=distance(clust[i].vec,clust[j].vec)

                    d=distances[(clust[i].id,clust[j].id)]

                if d<closest:
                    closest=d
                    lowestpair=(i,j)

            #calculate the average of the two cluster
            mergevec=[
            (clust[lowestpair[0]].vec[i]+clust[lowestpair[1]].vec[i])/2.0 
            for i in range(len(clust[0].vec))]

            #create the new cluster
            newcluster=bicluster(mergevec,left=clust[lowestpair[0]],
                                 right=clust[lowestpair[1]],
                                 distance=closest,id=currentclustid)

            #cluster ids that weren't in the original set are negative
            currentclustid-=1
            del clust[lowestpair[1]]
            del clust[lowestpair[0]]
            clust.append(newcluster)

        return clust[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lowestpair=(0.1)
```

That's a period, not a comma. `lowestpair` is a float, rather than a tuple. (While it looks like the error comes from `clust[0]`, Python tracebacks aren't very good at pointing out which physical line of a logical line an error comes from.)

Comment: I got it, it should be lowestpair=(0,1) not lowestpair=(0.1). Thank you!